# How to assess quality of model with quasi-binomial GLM residual plot?

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization, residuals, nonlinear-regression

I am currently completing quasi-binomial regression and I am using this line of R code to plot the residuals.

```
plot(residuals(mylogit) ~ predict(mylogit,type="link"),
  xlab=expression(hat(eta)),
  ylab="Deviance residuals")
```

I was wondering what do I expect in this plot to see if it is a good model or not.

Comment: Welcome to CV. It's not likely that model adequacy can be evaluated based on a graph. Among the other metrics to consider are its calibration, its performance in a holdout or k-fold cross-validation and the stability of the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

In principle, you would like to check if your residuals are "quasi-binomial distributed".

The issue with the quasi-families is that there is no clear generating model, so there is no quasi-binomial distribution that we could test against.

@havefun's advice of "You are plotting the residuals vs the fitted value, so you expect the points to scatter around zero without particular patterns" will often, but not always be correct. Simulations for the binomial show that in particular situations (low data, low counts), (deviance) residuals of a correctly specified model are indeed not homogeneous (see vignette below). I guess we can assume that the same applies for the quasi-binomial.

For a binomial, you could use the [DHARMa R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html), which uses simulations from the fitted model to transform the residuals of any GL(M)M into a standardized space. Once this is done, you can visually assess / test residual problems such as deviations from the distribution, residual dependency on a predictor, heteroskedasticity or autocorrelation in the normal way. See the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) for worked-through examples.

If your reason for using the quasi-binomial is to account for overdispersion, you could instead use a binomial with an observation-level random effect (see, e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4517959/), which would have the advantage that the generating model is known, and we can use binomial residual tests.

Answer (score 3):

You are plotting the residuals vs the fitted value, so you expect the points to 
scatter around zero without particular patterns (for example a positive correlation might mean that there are other hp you should test or you missed out an important variable)

That's the code I use to check it (just adding a line that should be straight)

`scatter.smooth(fitted(your_model), resid(your_model)); abline(h=0, lty=2)`

Without more info or the plot is difficult to say more.

have fun